# MDX Builder - filtering with INSTR function

Tags: select, mdx

I am totally new in MDX. I'd need to filter all records containing substring "SBP1". It works for me when I enter each record separately like this: 
`{[Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[SBP1  0],[Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[SBP1  1],[Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[SBP1  W]}`

[MDX builder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csvUP.jpg)

Working code:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Value]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[Article Alternative ID CPG].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Article].[Market].[Market].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Article].[Brand].[Brand].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Article].[Product].[Product].ALLMEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
      [Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[SBP1  0]
     ,[Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[SBP1  1]
     ,[Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[SBP1  W]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {[Measure Data Type].[Data Type].[Actuals]} ON COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        {[Org Sales Area].[Sales Organization Key].[DEB1]} ON COLUMNS
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          {[Org Sales Area].[Distribution Channel].&[DO]} ON COLUMNS
        FROM 
        (
          SELECT 
            {[Org Business Unit].[Business Unit].[U-K]} ON COLUMNS
          FROM 
          (
            SELECT 
              {[Measure Item].[Measure Item].&[KF00310]} ON COLUMNS
            FROM 
            (
              SELECT 
                {[Date of Posting].[Posting Y Q M D].[Posting Year].&[2017]} ON COLUMNS
              FROM [COLOR LEAN CPG]
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
WHERE 
  (
    [Date of Posting].[Posting Y Q M D].[Posting Year].&[2017]
   ,[Measure Item].[Measure Item].&[KF00310]
   ,[Org Business Unit].[Business Unit].[U-K]
   ,[Org Sales Area].[Distribution Channel].&[DO]
   ,[Org Sales Area].[Sales Organization Key].[DEB1]
   ,[Measure Data Type].[Data Type].[Actuals]
  )
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,FONT_NAME
 ,FONT_SIZE
 ,FONT_FLAG;
```

How could I do it more efficient with instr function?
I tried this but doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Value] ON COLUMNS
 ,Filter
  (
    [Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[Article Alternative ID CPG].ALLMEMBERS
   ,
      Instr
      (
        [Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[Article Alternative ID CPG].CurrentMember.Name
       ,'SBP1'
      )
    > 0
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [COLOR LEAN CPG];
```

What is wrong on my MDX statament?
[MDX with my SELECT screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcjY0.jpg)
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found a valid MDX statement: 

`Filter( [Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].ALLMEMBERS,Instr( [Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].currentmember.Properties( 'Member_Caption' ), 'SBP1' )  > 0)`

But this solution I didn't know to transform to pure GUI MDX BUILDER a insert it there.

Comment: this is what I said `I think you might have navigated a little far when applying the CURRENTMEMBER function` in my answer ... it was the main problem with your script

Comment: what does this mean? `But this solution I didn't know to transform to pure GUI MDX BUILDER a insert it there.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have navigated a little far when applying the `CURRENTMEMBER` function. Try this:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Value] ON COLUMNS
 ,Filter
  (
    [Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[Article Alternative ID CPG].ALLMEMBERS
   ,
      Instr
      (
        [Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].CurrentMember.Name   //<<[Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[Article Alternative ID CPG].CurrentMember.Name
       ,'SBP1'
      )
    > 0
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [COLOR LEAN CPG];
```

Hopefully name works for you but I usually go for `MEMBERCAPTION`:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Value] ON COLUMNS
 ,Filter
  (
    [Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[Article Alternative ID CPG].ALLMEMBERS
   ,
      Instr
      (
        [Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].CurrentMember.MEMBERCAPTION
       ,'SBP1'
      )
    > 0
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [COLOR LEAN CPG];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it still seems to be wrong (I tried  MEMBERCAPTION and aslo CurrentMember.Name):                            SELECT [Measures].[Value] ON COLUMNS,
Filter([Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[Article Alternative ID CPG].ALLMEMBERS,
Instr([Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].CurrentMember.MEMBERCAPTION,'SBP1')>0) ON ROWS
FROM [COLOR LEAN CPG];

Comment: "Thank you for your reply but it still seems to be wrong " .... if my answer was so wrong then how come in your solution you have used "[Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].CurrentMember"? Try doing it with your original implementation ! (this would never work `[Article].[Article Alternative ID CPG].[Article Alternative ID CPG].CurrentMember`)